# Android draw animated dotted curve

Tags: android, animation, bezier

I have been on this for days without finding a good solution (at least to me).

Basically what I need to do is draw an **animated dotted curve**, that would represent a **missile trajectory** for a basic game. This trajectory would accept  starting, middle and final x,y. I read a lot of Q/A about animating curves or even straight lines just to begin, but they look really complex compared to what I have to do.

I have a button with an `onclick` listener which triggers the missile launch, but until now it just draws static lines without any animation.

Do you remember this? That's what i would like to achieve:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDc3ZEKl-Wc

Banana trajectory is not painted but, you got the idea.

---

Here again, starting from your example i tried to draw simultaneous curves using arrays and for loops, but what i got is that sometimes, not always, app crashes with a nullpointer exception, don't know why. What am i doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
public class DrawDottedCurve extends View {

    Path[] path = new Path[8];
    Path[] drawingPath = new Path[8];
    PathMeasure[] measure = new PathMeasure[8];
    Path[] segmentPath = new Path[8];
    float[] length = new float[8];
    float[] start = new float[8];
    float[] percent = new float[8];
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    float x1;
    float y1;
    float x3;
    float y3;
    long k = 0;
    Canvas canvas;
    Random r = new Random();

    public DrawDottedCurve(Context context, int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        super(context);
        x1 = a;
        y1 = b;
        x3 = c;
        y3 = d;

        paint.setAlpha(255);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 2, 4 }, 50));

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            k = r.nextInt(100 - 30) + 30;
            path[i] = new Path();
            path[i].moveTo(x1 + k, y1 + k); //
            path[i].quadTo((x3 + k - x1 + k) / 2, (y3 + k - y1 + k) / 2,
                    x3 + k, y3 + k); // Calculate Bezier Curves
        }

        final long DRAW_TIME = 10000;
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(DRAW_TIME, 100) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.d("Timer", "Inizio");
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    start[i] = 0;
                    measure[i] = new PathMeasure();
                    measure[i].setPath(path[i], false);

                    percent[i] = ((float) (DRAW_TIME - millisUntilFinished))
                            / (float) DRAW_TIME;

                    segmentPath[i] = new Path();
                    drawingPath[i] = new Path();
                    length[i] = measure[i].getLength() * percent[i];
                    measure[i].getSegment(start[i], length[i], segmentPath[i],
                            true);
                    start[i] = length[i];
                    drawingPath[i].addPath(segmentPath[i]);


                }
                invalidate();
;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    measure[i].getSegment(start[i], measure[i].getLength(),
                            segmentPath[i], true);
                    drawingPath[i].addPath(segmentPath[i]);


                }

                invalidate();   
                Log.d("Timer", "Fine");
            }

        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            canvas.drawPath(drawingPath[i], paint);
            invalidate();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Calculate the points on a curve, a bezier curve e.g. and draw them one after another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a Canvas to draw on and a path you want to trace this code should do the work for animating it.

```
private void init() {
    missilePath = new Path();
    missileDrawPath = new Path();

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    PathEffect dashEffect = new DashPathEffect(new float[] {2, 4}, 0);
    mPaint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);

    final long DRAW_TIME = 5000;
    timer = new CountDownTimer(DRAW_TIME, 100) {
        PathMeasure measure = new PathMeasure();
        Path segmentPath = new Path();
        float start = 0;

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            measure.setPath(missilePath, false);
            float percent = ((float) (DRAW_TIME - millisUntilFinished)) / (float) DRAW_TIME;
            float length = measure.getLength() * percent;
            measure.getSegment(start, length, segmentPath, true);
            start = length;
            missileDrawPath.addPath(segmentPath);
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            measure.getSegment(start, measure.getLength(), segmentPath, true);
            missileDrawPath.addPath(segmentPath);
            invalidate();
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);
    c.drawPath(missileDrawPath, mPaint);
}
```

Basically a timer gets started and depending on the elapsed time a segment is retrieved from `missilePath` and added to the path that should be currently drawn.

Comment: I will implement the code in next few days and let you know. Thanks for now

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SceLus that worked really well, here's the full code for people eventually stuck on same problem.

Class constructor takes Bezier Curve starting and final x's and y's as input and simply calculate mid control point, then draws everything according to SceLus code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PathMeasure;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawDottedCurve extends View {

    Path path = new Path();
    Path drawingPath = new Path();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    float x1;
    float y1;
    float x3;
    float y3;

    public DrawDottedCurve(Context context, int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        super(context);

        x1 = a;
        y1 = b;
        x3 = c;
        y3 = d;

        paint.setAlpha(255);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 2, 4 }, 50));

        path.moveTo(x1, y1); //
        path.quadTo((x3 - x1) / 2, (y3 - y1) / 2, x3, y3); // Calculate Bezier Curve

        final long DRAW_TIME = 10000;
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(DRAW_TIME, 100) {
            PathMeasure measure = new PathMeasure();
            Path segmentPath = new Path();
            float start = 0;

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                measure.setPath(path, false);
                float percent = ((float) (DRAW_TIME - millisUntilFinished))
                        / (float) DRAW_TIME;
                float length = measure.getLength() * percent;
                measure.getSegment(start, length, segmentPath, true);
                start = length;
                drawingPath.addPath(segmentPath);
                invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                measure.getSegment(start, measure.getLength(), segmentPath,
                        true);
                drawingPath.addPath(segmentPath);
                invalidate();
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(drawingPath, paint);
    }
}
```